# Hypermarameters optimization in Gaussian Process in scikitlearn

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters

Are the hyper-parameters in Gaussian Process Regresor optimized during the fitting in scikit-learn?

In the page

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html

it is said:

"The hyperparameters of the kernel are optimized during fitting of GaussianProcessRegressor by maximizing the log-marginal-likelihood (LML) based on the passed optimizer"

So, it is not required, for instance, to optimize it by using grid earch?

Answer (score 0):

A hyperparameter is something that you need to specify, usually, the best way to do it is within a pipeline ( series of steps) in which you try many hyperparameters and get the best one. Here is an example of just trying different hyperparameters for a k-means in which you give a list of hyperparameters (n_neighbors for K-Means) in order to see which ones work best! Hope it helps you!

```
neighbors = np.arange(1, 9)
train_accuracy = np.empty(len(neighbors))
test_accuracy = np.empty(len(neighbors))

# Loop over different values of k
for i, k in enumerate(neighbors):
    # Setup a k-NN Classifier with k neighbors: knn
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors= k)

  # Fit the classifier to the training data
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)

  #Compute accuracy on the training set
   train_accuracy[i] = knn.score(X_train, y_train)

   knn.predict(X_test)

  #Compute accuracy on the testing set
   test_accuracy[i] = knn.score(X_test, y_test)

# Generate plot
plt.title('k-NN: Varying Number of Neighbors')
plt.plot(neighbors, test_accuracy, label = 'Testing Accuracy')
plt.plot(neighbors, train_accuracy, label = 'Training Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Number of Neighbors')
```